# C++ Macros with multiple statements

Tags: c++, replace, macros, c-preprocessor

I am analyzing the source of the FileTransfer open source project from sourceforge. I'm new to C++ and I came across the following macro:

```
#define USES_CONVERSION int _convert; (_convert); UINT _acp = ATL::_AtlGetConversionACP() /*CP_THREAD_ACP*/; (_acp); LPCWSTR _lpw; (_lpw); LPCSTR _lpa; (_lpa)
```

I understand the basic idea of the replacements done by the preprocessor in simple macros like:

```
#define PI 3.14
```

But I don't understand a long macro like the one shown above (first one). Will someone please explain that?

Comment: It's not hard really, the preprocessor mostly does textual replacements agnostic of the programming language (C++ here), so it just expands `USES_CONVERSION` anywhere it sees that token with the entire text following it on the `#define` line, as if by copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just replaces he occurrence of

```
USES_CONVERSION
```

with the code

```
int _convert; (_convert); UINT _acp = ATL::_AtlGetConversionACP() /*CP_THREAD_ACP*/; (_acp); LPCWSTR _lpw; (_lpw); LPCSTR _lpa; (_lpa)
```

It is just a simple text replacement

Comment: so what is the meaning of `(_convert);` 

What does it evaluate to? Thanks

Comment: The is a C/C++ trick to avoid the warning of not using a declared variable. (in addition useful for adding breakpoints).

Answer (score 0):

In other word, that is a macro function. and can use in the case that someone implement getter and setter in C# language with C language.

but in c++ language, we don't recommend this usage because it is not easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

The macro is a part of ATL library, defined in atlmfc\include\atlconv.h, and it creates local variables which is used by other macros defined in the atlconv.h, like A2W, W2A.
Its purpose is providing convenient way to convert between different types of character arrays (ansi, widechars).